# getting int with unknown length using getchar()

Tags: c, int

I want to write a code that gets a number with unknown number of digits (means it can both 100 and 1000000). I thought of using `getchar` and wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char nextdigit;
  int finalnumber=0;
  nextdigit=getchar(); 

  while(nextdigit!='\n')
  {
    finalnumber=finalnumer*10+(int)nextdigit;
    nextdigit=getchar();
  }
  printf("%d",finalnumber);
}
```

but seems like when I enter for example `3` it prints 51 (maybe the ascii value of `3` ) and in fact doesn't allow me to enter digits anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `51` is the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of `'3'`. There is an easy way to get a characters ASCII value to the integer value though, just subtract the ASCII Value of `'0'`:

```
finalnumber = finalnumer * 10 + nextdigit - '0';
```

---

Also, be careful when using `char` variables with `getchar`, as `getchar` is declared to return an `int`. You might also want to check for `EOF` being returned (which is why you need an `int` variable).

Comment: Side-Insight: Interesting here is that the standard guarantees 0..9 to be contiguous. Otherwise, this would be, by C++ law, not by fact, a non-portable trick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416926/are-the-character-digits-0-9-required-to-have-contiguous-numeric-values).

Comment: @phresnel My guess is that it's in the standard because so many applications already had that. I find it funny though that the same is not said for letters, even though it's just as common. But that's probably because there already was at least one character set (EBDIC) where that wasn't true.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` returns `int`. Declare `nextdigit` as `int`.

```
int nextdigit;
```

and subtract `48` (the ascii value of `'0'`) from the expression `finalnumber = finalnumber*10 + nextdigit;`

```
finalnumber = finalnumber*10 + nextdigit - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get ASCII so remove : 0x30 ('0')

You probably will have to do something about the '-' (because you are entering an int) otherwise use unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically simplify your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number;
    printf("Enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("Number was: %d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that depends on how big your input number is

```
short int          - 32768 ~ 32767      scanf("%d", &number);
unsigned int         0 ~ 2^32 -1        scanf("%u", &number);
int                 - 2^31 ~ 2^31 - 1   scanf("%d", &number);
int 64              - 2^63 ~ 2^63 - 1   scanf("%I64d", &number);
```

if your input is bigger than 2^63 - 1 you should try use char as input
and each input character of type char is its ASCII value

```
  char nextdigit;
  int finalnumber=0;
  nextdigit=getchar(); 
  finalnumber=nextdigit-'0';
```