# Convert a digit char to an int (same az the char) in c++

Tags: c++

I have an array that is char and all of them are numbers but in type of Char means:

```
myArray = ['5','6','8','9','10',....]
```

for example i wnat to add two of them.i must to convert them to integer and then add them together but using:

```
(int)myArray[1]+(int)myArray[2]
```

give a wrong answer.
what is the function or the correct way for doing this?

Comment: '10' is not a char...

Comment: Please post actual, relevant code

Comment: exci=use me yo're right and this was my mistake.excuse me

Comment: @Jekyll:  Multibyte literals are allowed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes I've seen it (tried). This is something I never tried before, I was surprised :). But I'll do better removing the comment :D

Answer (score 5):

For [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) digit chars from `'0'` - `'9'`, one can substract the value of `'0'`, since their values are contiguous:

```
char digit = '7' ; //any char, from '0' ... '9'
int value = digit - '0';
```

Further information: [Are the character digits ['0'..'9'] required to have contiguous numeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9416926/1175253)

Comment: For **all** encodings this is required. It's just about the only thing that's portable across encodings.

Comment: @Pete Becker : Thank you for pointing that out. I've read up a bit, starting at the link I added. Until now, I never questioned the portability of my code regarding alphanumeric ranges.

Comment: I usually thump people for making ASCII-centric assumptions, so I appreciate your caution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function atoi, for example:

```
char str[] = "122";
int i = atoi(str);
```

Notice that you must use the double quotes (") for strings. The single quotes (') work only for characters.

Also, you must add this include:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```