# what does putchar('0' + num); do?

Tags: c, putchar

I am trying to understand how the `putchar('0' + r);` works. Below, the function takes an integer and transform it to binary.

```
void to_binary(unsigned long n)
{
   int r;
   r = n % 2;
   if (n >= 2)
      to_binary(n / 2);
   putchar('0' + r);
}
```

I google the definition of [putchar](http://man.he.net/man3/putchar) but I didn't find this. To test it, I added a printf to see the value of the r:

```
void to_binary(unsigned long n)
{
   int r;
   r = n % 2;
   if (n >= 2)
      to_binary(n / 2);
   printf("r = %d and putchar printed ", r);
   putchar('0' + r);
   printf("\n");
}
```

and I run it (typed 5) and got this output:

> > r = 1  and putchar printed 1
> >     r = 0  and putchar printed 0
> >     r = 1  and putchar printed 1

So I suppose that the `putchar('0' + r);`  prints 0 if r=0, else prints 1 if r=1, or something else happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C `'0' + digit` is a cheap way of converting a single-digit integer into its character representation, like ASCII or EBCDIC. For example if you use `ASCII` think of it as adding 0x30 (`'0'`) to a digit.

The one assumption is that the character encoding has a contiguous area for digits - which holds for both ASCII and EBCDIC.

---

As pointed out in the comments this property is required by both the C++ and C standards. The C standard says:

> **5.2.1 - 3**
>
> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>   each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>   one greater than the value of the previous.

Comment: "The one assumption .." is actually *required*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416926/are-the-character-digits-0-9-required-to-have-contiguous-numeric-values

Comment: @Jongware Thanks. I added the quote for the C standard - I didn't know if C++ also had this.

Comment: However keep in mind that if you're writing a file or network stream parser that has to work from a specific character set you should code it against the numeric values found in that character set, just to be clear about it (also to somebody reading the code).

Answer (score 4):

`'0'` represents an integer equal to 48 in decimal and is the ASCII code for the character `0` (zero). The ASCII code for the character for `1` is 49 in decimal.

`'0' + r` is the same as `48 + r`. When r = 0, the expression evaluates to 48 so a `0` is outputted. On the other hand, when r = 1, the expression evaluates to 49 so a `1` is outputted. In other words, `'0' + 1 == '1'`

Basically, it's a nice way to convert decimal digits to their ASCII character representations easily. It also works with the alphabet (i.e. `'A' + 2` is the same as `C`)

Comment: The part about `'A' + n` is not always true with EBCDIC systems... See cnicutar's answer.

Comment: Indeed, the standard doesn't enforce `'A'+n`, not even with a lower limit (such as making it mandatory for the first six letters). It *happens* to work in ASCII for all unaccented latin letters and in EBCDIC for A to I (enabling easy hexadecimal conversion), but a charset could exist without such trait.

Answer (score 2):

***It's a common technique used for `char` handing.***

`char a = '0' + r` (r in [0,9]) will convert an integer to its char format based on given char base (i.e. `'0'` in this case), you will get `'0'...'9'`

Similarly, `char a = 'a' + r` or `char a = 'A' + r` (r in [0,25]) will convert an integer to its char format, you will get `'a'...'z'` or `'A'...'Z'` (*except for [EBCDIC systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) which has discontinuous area for alphabets*).

---

**Edit:**

1. You can also do the other way around, for example:

   ```
   char myChar = 'c';
   int b = myChar - 'a'; // b will be 2
   ```
2. Similar idea is used to convert a lowercase char to uppercase:

   ```
   char myChar = 'c';
   char newChar = myChar - 'a' + 'A'; // newChar will be 'C'
   ```

Comment: The part about `'A' + n` and the character codes for the alphabet in general is not always true with EBCDIC systems... See cnicutar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

U are adding the ASCII value of the number's 
say '0' ASCII value is 48

'1' -> 49,and so on [CHECK HERE FOR COMPLETE TABLE](http://ascii.cl/)

so when u add one to 48 it will 49 and putchar functuion prints the character sent to it. when u do

```
putchar('0' + r )
```

if r = 1 putchar(48 + 1) (converting into ASCII value)

putchar(49) which is 1